# how to decode UTF8 charset of a subject line of a received email

Tags: php

While working with IMAP email headers in PHP , I encountered an issue which is related to encoding of subject line. When I am try `mb_decode_mimeheader` (as per the duplicate issue) then I am not getting desired result:

```
$subject = "=?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?= Your winning day =?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?=";
echo mb_decode_mimeheader($subject);
```

Output:

```
? Your winning day ?
```

Comment: @peter when i am trying mb_decode_mimeheader than I am not getting desired result code i am using is : $subject="=?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?= Your winning day =?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?=";
echo $sub=mb_decode_mimeheader($subject);output:? Your winning day ?

Comment: Voting to reopen, the linked duplicate does not really solve this problem. @abhinav Please post your code into the question next time to make the problem more specific.

Comment: Please update with two more data points, so that question has all 3 -- expected output, output using answer accepted in duplicate, output using the other answer in duplicate.

Comment: Testing with Python OP string evaluates to U+2663 (black spaces suit) + text + same unicode char, i.e. `♣Your winning day♣`. I suppose OP issue is missing unicode. Perhaps all OP needs is echo utf8_encode(mb_....);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix the example in the comments:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$subject = "=?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?= Your winning day =?UTF-8?Q?=e2=99=a3?=";
echo mb_decode_mimeheader($subject);
```

Outputs "♣ Your winning day ♣".

It's undocumented that `mb_internal_encoding` influences the operation of `mb_decode_mimeheader`, but it does. `mb_internal_encoding` is taken as the target charset that should be returned from `mb_decode_mimeheader`. If that's set to Latin-1, then characters like "♣" cannot be decoded into this target charset and will fail.

You may want to look at [`imap_utf8`](http://php.net/imap_utf8) for a less finicky function.

Comment: when i am trying to execute snippet of code provided by you i am getting outout: â™£ Your winning day â™£ is there any way to overcome this.Please it might be low level question for you , but i am bit new with IMAP so i am facing these trouble. Thanks in advance for your help and guidance.But still i am searching to find a way how can i accomplish my requirement.

Comment: yes @abhinav you are right i too getting same output deceze how you got your output as  "♣ Your winning day ♣".Though I too trying same code and getting same output as mentioned by abhinav. Few days back I too stuck at same problem.

Comment: @abhinav That means everything works fine, but you're not displaying the result as UTF-8. Where are you displaying this? Also see http://kunststube.net/frontback.

Comment: I am just trying to display it on browser using xampp, is there any setting required to modify in php ini file.

Comment: @abhinav See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through in addition to the link I gave above.

Comment: Hey deceze you are rock star bro it working now your link  kunststube.net/frontback solved my problem thank you very much.In addition to your snippet of code i added header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); and with it it works fine.